# Model.fit with ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

```
when I run the model training
```

`history = model.fit(X_train, epochs=10, validation_data=X_val, callbacks=callbacks)`

I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-220b28513468> in <module>()
      6     )
      7 ]
----> 8 history = model.fit(X_train, epochs=10, validation_data=X_val, callbacks=callbacks)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1153               (x, y, sample_weight), validation_split=validation_split))
   1154 
-> 1155     if validation_data:
   1156       val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight = (
   1157           data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(validation_data))

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It appears to be in X_val, it contains the same data as x_trein, with other values.

Comment: Try `validation_data=(X_val, y_val)`

Comment: Reread what `fit` expects for the `validation_data` parameter.  Clearly an array (by itself) isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, and solved it as follows.

validation_data = x
->validation_data = (x, None)

Thank you.